# Why is Python not JSON Standard (rfc7159) Compliant by default?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

The Python3 standard lib for JSON, https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html, documents the following (emphasis mine):

> If allow_nan is false (default: True), then it will be a ValueError to
> serialize out of range float values (nan, inf, -inf) **in strict**
> **compliance of the JSON specification**. If allow_nan is true, their
> JavaScript equivalents (NaN, Infinity, -Infinity) will be used.

Further down on the encoder:

> If allow_nan is true (the default), then NaN, Infinity, and -Infinity
> will be encoded as such. **This behavior is not JSON specification**
> **compliant**, but is consistent with most JavaScript based encoders and
> decoders. Otherwise, it will be a ValueError to encode such floats.

While it is good they allow this as an option for those who are capable of deliberately parsing NaN, why doesn't Python follow the JSON spec as the default?

Comment: "...but is consistent with most JavaScript based encoders and decoders". That's why. Being useful in practice is more important than being technically correct and adhering to the standard, when doing so would break other things you're likely to have to interact with.

Comment: Probably because "but is consistent with *most* (emphasis mine) JavaScript based encoders and decoders".

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I'm here because Python's behaviour causes it to emit invalid data over an API that cannot be parsed in several languages. It's hardly breaking things to follow this standard.

Comment: @BookOfGreg can you be more specific as to what the behavior is that causes the problem?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is in the same sentence: because it's consistent with other encoders and decoders that don't follow the standard.

JSON was not standardized until 2013, and the decision to require out-of-range values to raise an error was probably made *despite* the fact that common practice was to generate special values.

There are *de jure* standards (like EMCA-404/RFC 8259/ISO/IEC 21778:2017), and there are *de facto* standards (which is what everyone does in the absence of a real standard or for backwards compatibility to pre-standard practice).

Comment: Given Python 3 came out in 2008 this is much more likely to be the correct answer than the speculation about usefulness. Thank you.